# Trigger to delete rows when column field reaches 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have to create a trigger that automatically deletes rows when the Quantity field reaches 0 but after running an update that makes Quantity = 0 it gives me this error:

> Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Deleterow
AFTER UPDATE
ON Sold
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM Sold WHERE NEW.Quantity = 0
```

Comment: tag your dbms please

Answer (score 2):

you can't do this with trigger in mysql , see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

instead you can make an `event` and schedule to delete those rows for you :

```
create event deletesold
on schedule at  current_timestamp + interval 1 hour
    DO
      delete from sold where Quantity = 0;
```

Comment: I'll see more about events then, thank you!